# trigger pipeline for multi-project pipelines without maintainer permissions

Tags: gitlab-ci

I have two projects A and B each with their own CI/CD pipelines. Project A has a trigger implemented that invokes the pipeline of project B when something is committed/merged to the master branch.

The following chart roughly describes the workflow:

```
A (master) -> Pipeline A      /-> trigger -> B (master) -> Pipeline B
      ^       |- Job 1..N-1  /                             |- Job 1 - Prepare
    commit    \- Job N  ----/                              |- Job 2 - Load dependency A, C, ...
                                                           |- Job 3 - Build, etc.
```

The goal is that a maintainer of project A can merge to the master branch of their component and
then the pipeline is triggered in Project B which has a dependency on project A but also other dependencies such as dependency C (not shown here). Upstream pipelines put their artifacts into a package repository (i.e., npm, pip, nuget, docker, etc.) and the downstream project fetches the most recent dependency from there to create a new build.

Whenever an upstream project changes the downstream project should be rebuild using the most recent dependency of the corresponding upstream project. This ensures that we catch issues due to changes in upstream projects automatically and that we always have a most recent downstream version with the latest upstream changes integrated.

The maintainer of project A usually does not have maintainer permissions for project B. The issue is that this causes a permission error `no permission to trigger downstream pipeline` on the trigger job when the upstream pipeline is executed by the maintainer (who accepts a merge request for their project).

I am wondering if this is a limitation of Gitlab's CI/CD implementation or if this is a design problem in the pipeline that could be solved by a different implementation/workflow.

This is the trigger that is implemented in project A to invoke the pipeline of project B:

```
trigger:upstream:
  stage: deploy
  trigger: group-1/group-2/project-b
  rules:
    - if: '$CI_COMMIT_REF_PROTECTED == "true" && ($CI_COMMIT_TAG =~ /^$/ || $CI_COMMIT_TAG =~ /^v.*$/)'
```

Comment: This is an issue that's been documented and unfortunately there is still no workaround except escalating the permissions of the users triggering the pipelines: https://gitlab.com/gitlab-org/gitlab/-/issues/326941